# How to track who downloaded the source code from VSTS (Azure DevOps)

Tags: azure-devops

We are using VSTS (Azure DevOps) as the source control tool. We have to track who is downloading the source code from VSTS (Azure DevOps).

Is there any options to get the complete details of the work-station machine (source code downloaded machine) like IP address, location, pc name, date-time, etc...

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Do you work with TFVC or GIT?

Comment: No. Earlier, we have used TFS 2017. Now, we migrated to VSTS (Azure DevOps). Is there any way to handle this problem?